# How to slow or remove the animation of a step change of Angular Material Stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-stepper

I would like to ask if it is possible to change the speed of the animation when the user clicks to the next or previous step.

Is there any way of doing it?

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpoj5j?file=app%2Fcreate-profile.component.html) you can see an example of a Stepper.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatStepper) says you need to use "animationDuration".